# CodePipeline, CodeBuild, CloudFormation, Lambda: build multiple lambdas in a single build and assign their code correctly

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I have a CD pipeline built with AWS CDK and CodePipeline. It compiles the code for 5 lambdas, each of which it pushes to a secondary artifact.

The S3 locations of each of the artifacts are assigned to the parameters of a CloudFormation template which are attached to the `Code` parts of the lambdas.

This is working fine!

My problem is, I cannot add a sixth secondary artifact to CodeBuild (hard limit). I also cannot combine all of my lambda code into a single artifact as (as far as I can see) CodePipeline is not smart enough to look inside an artifact when assigning `Code` to a lambda in CloudFormation.

What is the recommendation for deploying multiple lambdas from a CodeBuild/CodePipeline? How have other people solved this issue?

**EDIT: Code pipeline CF template**
note: I have only included 2 lambdas as an example

Lambda application template

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Resources": {
    "Lambda1": {
      "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Function",
      "Properties": {
        "Code": {
          "S3Bucket": {
            "Ref": "lambda1SourceBucketNameParameter3EE73025"
          },
          "S3Key": {
            "Ref": "lambda1SourceObjectKeyParameter326E8288"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "Lambda2": {
      "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Function",
      "Properties": {
        "Code": {
          "S3Bucket": {
            "Ref": "lambda2SourceBucketNameParameter3EE73025"
          },
          "S3Key": {
            "Ref": "lambda2SourceObjectKeyParameter326E8288"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "Parameters": {
    "lambda1SourceBucketNameParameter3EE73025": {
      "Type": "String"
    },
    "lambda1SourceObjectKeyParameter326E8288": {
      "Type": "String"
    },
    "lambda2SourceBucketNameParameterA0D2319B": {
      "Type": "String"
    },
    "lambda2SourceObjectKeyParameterF3B3F2C2": {
      "Type": "String"
    }
  }
}
```

Code Pipeline template:

```
{
  "Resources": {
    "Pipeline40CE5EDC": {
      "Type": "AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline",
      "Properties": {
        "Stages": [
          {
            "Actions": [
              {
                "ActionTypeId": {
                  "Provider": "CodeBuild"
                },
                "Name": "CDK_Build",
                "OutputArtifacts": [
                  {
                    "Name": "CdkbuildOutput"
                  }
                ],
                "RunOrder": 1
              },
              {
                "ActionTypeId": {
                  "Provider": "CodeBuild"
                },
                "Name": "Lambda_Build",
                "OutputArtifacts": [
                  { "Name": "CompiledLambdaCode1" },
                  { "Name": "CompiledLambdaCode2" }
                ],
                "RunOrder": 1
              }
            ],
            "Name": "Build"
          },
          {
            "Actions": [
              {
                "ActionTypeId": {
                  "Provider": "CloudFormation"
                },
                "Configuration": {
                  "StackName": "DeployLambdas",
                  "ParameterOverrides": "{\"lambda2SourceBucketNameParameterA0D2319B\":{\"Fn::GetArtifactAtt\":[\"CompiledLambdaCode1\",\"BucketName\"]},\"lambda2SourceObjectKeyParameterF3B3F2C2\":{\"Fn::GetArtifactAtt\":[\"CompiledLambdaCode1\",\"ObjectKey\"]},\"lambda1SourceBucketNameParameter3EE73025\":{\"Fn::GetArtifactAtt\":[\"CompiledLambdaCode2\",\"BucketName\"]},\"lambda1SourceObjectKeyParameter326E8288\":{\"Fn::GetArtifactAtt\":[\"CompiledLambdaCode2\",\"ObjectKey\"]}}",
                  "ActionMode": "CREATE_UPDATE",
                  "TemplatePath": "CdkbuildOutput::CFTemplate.template.json"
                },
                "InputArtifacts": [
                  { "Name": "CompiledLambdaCode1" },
                  { "Name": "CompiledLambdaCode2" },
                  { "Name": "CdkbuildOutput" }
                ],
                "Name": "Deploy",
                "RunOrder": 1
              }
            ],
            "Name": "Deploy"
          }
        ],
        "ArtifactStore": {
          "EncryptionKey": "the key",
          "Location": "the bucket",
          "Type": "S3"
        },
        "Name": "Pipeline"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are they in different buckets? Can't you put them all in one artifact store?

Comment: Same bucket, same artifact store. I don't see how that relates to the issue, can you explain?

Comment: So where are those 5 artifacts of yours comming from that you hit the limit?

Comment: Directly from code build. The "secondary-artifacts"

Comment: Can you clarify your design. You have: CP source action -> 1 CB build action creating 5 CFN lambda templates -> 5 deploy actions with CFN providers which creates the lambdas from the templates (one per template)?

Comment: Are you saying CodePipeline is not smart enough to look for an archive within a archive?

Can you post your cloudformation template so I can understand the structure of it and the pipeline?

Comment: @TimBassett , yes that is what I am saying. Issue edited, templates added

Comment: @Marcin CP source action -> 1 CB build action creating 1 CFN lambda template with 5 lambdas in it -> 1 deploy action with CFN providers which creates the lambdas from the template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reviewed templates.

So, I don't see five inputs to a CodeBuild action, but I do see 2 inputs to a CloudFormation action (Deploy).

I *assume* your problem was a perceived limit of 5 input to the CloudFormation action.  Is that assumption correct?

The limits for a CloudFormation action are actually 10.  See "Action Type Constraints for Artifacts
" @ https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/reference-pipeline-structure.html#reference-action-artifacts

So if you can use up to 10, will that suffice?

If not, I have other ideas that would take a lot longer to document.

Comment: Thanks for that. And yes, your assumption is correct :) . In the document supplied, it says 10 input artifacts for CF, but only 5 output artifacts for CodeBuild.
My goal here is to plan for the future. In a given domain, we might have 20/30 lambdas as our code base grows, so I am making sure that our choice of infrastructure can support that in the long run

Comment: Ok.  Well, if you have more than 10, your options are to package some of them together.  I have 30 or 40 in a package, nested stacks or a CustomResource to unzip the master zip.

Other than that, can you mark this as the answer?

Comment: What happens when you pack (let's say)10 lambdas in one artefact? how do you refer to each of them individually in the CF template?

Comment: You should be able to refer to each of the 10 of them via the handler.  Or up to 500 of them,